# Average over Group By SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the command:

```
SELECT
  number_of_pairs,
  COUNT(*) --/(SUM(COUNT)) AS Percentage
FROM result
WHERE number_of_pairs!= 'NULL'
GROUP BY 1;
```

Which results in :

[image]

But my objective is not to know the count of each group but the percentage of each group count with respect the total. 
I have tried:

```
COUNT(*)/(SUM(COUNT)) AS Percentage
```

But doesn't return anything.

I would like to get `379/(379+371)=0.505` in the first row and `371/(379+371)=...` in the second

SQLite version : 3.11.0

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well,

Comment: I am using SQLite

Comment: Do you mean the string `'379/(379+371)'`, or its calculated result?

Comment: The result of the quotient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` window function to get the total:

```
SELECT
  number_of_pairs,
  1.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS Percentage
FROM result
WHERE number_of_pairs <> 'NULL'
GROUP BY number_of_pairs;
```

Unless you actually have `'NULL'` as a string literal in column `number_of_pairs`, you must change the condition to:

```
number_of_pairs IS NOT NULL
```

For older versions of SQLite that do not support window functions:

```
SELECT
  r.number_of_pairs,
  1.0 * COUNT(*) / MAX(t.counter) AS Percentage
FROM result r 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) counter FROM result WHERE number_of_pairs <> 'NULL') t
WHERE r.number_of_pairs <> 'NULL'
GROUP BY r.number_of_pairs;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=026460962970e9baee024859e06c1c0c).

Comment: I do not know why but your 

1.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS Percentage

Does not return me anything. Yeah my NULL is really a 'NULL'

Comment: What is your SQLite version?

Comment: It is the one in CodeAcademy browser, how do I check it?

Comment: Execute: `select sqlite_version();`

Comment: 3.11.0 is the version

Comment: See my 2nd query, without window functions.

Comment: Does not work and I cannot share the data as I cannot download it

Comment: Check the demo  in my answer for both queries.